# Anti-homomorphism of Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

I've got a quick question regarding the anti-homomorphism property. Specifically, what does it actually mean??

For a bit of context, I have the following question.

We define $U_q = U_q[o(3)]$ to be the associative algebra, with generators $L_0$, $L_+$ and $L_-$, with the defining relations; $[L_0, L_{\pm}] = \pm L_{\pm}$, $[L_+, L_-] = (q^{2L_0} - q^{-2L_0}) / (q - q^{-1})$.

The antipode has been defined such that $$S(I) = I$$ $$S(L_0) = -L_0$$  $$S(L_{\pm}) = -q^{-L_0} L_{\pm}q^{L_0} = -q^{\mp1}L_{\pm}$$

I'm being asked to show that $S$ constitutes an anti-homomorphism, for the $L_0$ and $L_{\pm}$ generators. However, I'm not really sure how to go about this, because I'm not too sure what the anti-homomorphism actually looks like, or really means.

Any insight into this would be great. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is an algebra, then anti-homomorphism $\phi:A\to A$ is a linear map such that $$\phi(x\cdot y)=\phi(y)\cdot\phi(x).$$ In your situation, you are probably being asked to show that there exists an anti-homomorphism $S$ which acts as you were told on the generators of the algebra.

**A simple example**, different from the one you want, so as not to ruin your problem:

Let $A$ be the algebra generated by two letters $x$ and $y$ subject to the relation $$yx-xy=1.$$ I claim there is a unique anti-homomorphism $\phi:A\to A$ such that $\phi(x)=y$ and $\phi(y)=-x$.

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now. Thank you!!

Comment: Actually, I do have another question now, if you might be able to help??

I've been trying to show the anti-homomorphism for the $L_{\pm}$, with the hint that we need to show it preserves the commutation relations. So, I'm kind of assuming that we need to show $S([a,b]) = [S(a), S(b)]$, for some $a$ and $b$ within $L_{\pm}$. So, the LHS goes to;
$$S([a,b]) = S(ab - ba) = -q^{\mp 1} (ab-ba) = q^{\mp 1} (ba - ab)$$

My issue is the RHS;

$$[S(a), S(b)] = S(a)S(b) - S(b)S(a) = (-q^{\mp 1}b)(-q^{\mp 1}a) - (-q^{\mp 1}a)((-q^{\mp 1}b) = (q^{\mp 1}b)(q^{\mp 1}a) - (q^{\mp 1}a)((q^{\mp 1}b)$$

Comment: So, my question is, what happens with the $q^{\mp 1}$ terms??

Comment: Yo do not want to show that $S$ *preserves* the commutation relations: it has to *reverse* them! Since $S$ is an anti-homomorphism, you will have $$S([a,b])=S(ab-ba)=S(ab)-S(ba)=S(b)S(a)-S(a)S(b)=-[S(a),S(B)]$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an associative algebra then its opposite algebra $A^{op}$ is defined on the same underlying vector space but with multiplication 
$$
x\cdot y=yx
$$
In the LHS, $x\cdot y$ stands for the multiplication in $A^{op}$, while on the RHS $yx$ stands for the original multiplication (in $A$).

Then, an antihomomorphsism $\phi:A\to A$ is (by definition) an homomorphism  $\phi:A\to A^{op}$ from $A$ to the opposite algebra $A^{op}$. So, the antipode $S$ of a Hopf algebra $H$ is simply an algebra homomorphism $S:H\to H^{op}$.